# MySQL--unknown column in field list

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mariadb

I don't see why the UPDATE below works fine in the console but fails in my Java code

```
MariaDB [testdb]> DESCRIBE datasift_geo;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| datasift_id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| latitude    | decimal(17,14)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| longitude   | decimal(17,14)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| location    | varchar(100)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| coord       | point               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [testdb]> SELECT * FROM datasift_geo;
+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-------+
| datasift_id | latitude          | longitude         | location   | coord |
+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-------+
|        1601 | 51.45713800000000 | -2.60802800000000 | Bristol UK | NULL  |
+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+-------+

MariaDB [testdb]> UPDATE datasift_geo SET coord = GeomFromText('POINT(51.45713800000000 -2.60802800000000)');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

================

```
@Test
public void testGeoCoord() throws SQLException {
    int id = 1601;
    float latitude = 51.45713806152344f;
    float longitude = -2.608027935028076f;
    String sql = "UPDATE `datasift_geo` SET `datasift_geo`.`coord` = GeomFromText('POINT(" + latitude + " " + longitude + ")') WHERE datasift_id = " + id;
    // get database connection, create a PreparedStatement, execute the UPDATE
}
```

======

Result of executing the UPDATE

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'datasift_geo.coord'
>   in 'field list'

Comment: Why not just `coord` (as you do in console exampe)?

Comment: That's a good question. I've tried any number of permutations thinking the backticks may be the problem, but all with the same result--unknown column.

Comment: I know you already checked many options but we developer always make silly mistakes. I hope you are connecting to proper host and database. It may possible table exists but not the column.

Comment: I feel really stupid right now. I was attaching to a different database in my Java code versus my unit test code and console connection. When I switched to the correct database it worked as anticipated. Please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Happy to know that your issue got resolved :) Happens at times :)

Answer (score 1):

From the SQL which you have written in the JAVA code, it seems that you have provided `tableName.ColumnName`, in the SQL. You should only provide the column name.

```
String sql = "UPDATE `datasift_geo` SET **`datasift_geo`.`coord`** = GeomFromText('POINT(" + latitude + " " + longitude + ")') WHERE datasift_id = " + id;
```

**Syntax is:** *UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME*
**Your Java Code has:**  *UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME* -- Wrong

Also it can be seen from the Exception

So, your SQL in Jave Code should be as follows:

```
String sql = "UPDATE `datasift_geo` SET `coord` = GeomFromText('POINT(" + latitude + " " + longitude + ")') WHERE datasift_id = " + id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A System.out.prinltn of the SQL string returns "UPDATE datasift_geo SET coord = GeomFromText('POINT(51.457138 -2.608028)') WHERE datasift_id = 1601" -- but this continues to throw the unknown column name error

Comment: Now this is interesting. Please double check, if in case, there's some misspelling with the column name. These are some of the silly mistake(s), which we developer do some times :) :)